# global submatch()?

Tags: vim, global, substitution

I wanted to find a line, then match several words within that line BUT instead of substituting them I would prefer to simply save them (by appending to a register, or exporting to a file).

Is back-referencing (i.e. submatch(1) or \1) doable in this regards, or is that only through the substitution?  I realize I could substitute back to the file I am working on - altering it - but I would prefer to export it.

Is there a way to call a function (to save the submatch) within substitute without damaging the file?  Or, preferably, use the global search to capture a portion of the line and then pass that as a parameter onto a function call that would do the saving as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for `:h :global` and do something like this:

```
:g/pattern/call func_to_get_and_save_text()
```

That would call the function on every line matching the given pattern.

Comment: Interesting...  Never knew that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
:%s/pattern \(saved portion\)/\=[submatch(0), SaverFunc(submatch(1))][0]/
```

or

```
:%s/pattern \(saved portion\)\zs/\=SaverFunc(submatch(1))[-1]
```

. In last case SaverFunc must return either string or number (without explicit `:return` statement it will return number 0). It does not matter which string or number will be returned: `string_or_number[-1]` always expands to an empty string.

Comment: note that `submatch(0)` is the whole matched string (so no capturing groups are required for simple patterns); Alternatively, `\zs` and `\ze` can be used to control the part of the match returned